# Why is an "identifier" considered ambiguous with "identifier()" when they're used differently?

Tags: c++

**This is solely for example I happen to notice with!**

I'm using `cout` with `operator<<` and why won't this program compile?
Why aren't they being considered the way function overloadings are?

```cpp
#include <iostream> // imports the declaration of std::cout

using namespace std; // makes std::cout accessible as "cout"

int cout() // declares our own "cout" function
{
    return 5;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, world!"; // Compile error!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's what `using namespace std;` means: treat **all** identifiers that are defined in `std` as if they were defined in the global namespace. So when you add **another** definition of `cout` to the global namespace you get a conflict. Short answer: **don't write `using namespace std;`.**

Comment: `Why aren't they considered as function overloading when they're used differently?` because `std::cout` isn't a function.

Comment: I apologize for closing this as duplicate.  While you're asking a slightly different question, I believe you will find the answer in that post.

Comment: @paddy -- I reopened the question, since you say you closed it in error.

Comment: @tkausl I got it. Compiler was unable to distinguish between `cout()`'s identifier and `std::cout`.

Comment: @tkausl -- but even `std::cout` was a function, there is no function call, so there would be no overloading.

Comment: Note that it is perfectly possible to use an object name with parentheses and to use a function name without parentheses, so a compiler can't distinguish between a function and an object with the same name based on whether they are used with parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the point of the attempted stream insertion, there are two names `cout` in global scope: one from the standard library, `std::cout`, pulled into global scope by that infernal `using` declaration, and one defined as a function `int cout()`. In the expression

```
cout << "Hello, world!\n";
```

the use of `cout` is ambiguous. There is no function overloading for two reasons: first, `std::cout` is not a function, so would not take part in overloading. But more fundamentally, the use of `cout` in that expression is not a function call, so, again, there is no overloading. The name `cout` from the function definition is treated as a pointer to function, and the name `cout` from namespace `std` is the name of an object. There are two possible interpretations of that name, so its use in that `<<` expression is ambiguous.

Comment: That's a good explanation. But I don't know why people down voting my question. If possible, I'd like to keep this alive for future readers who are confused like me.

Comment: @MichaelD.Blake My best guess is that it's the unfortunate habit of many SO users to downvote questions if the problem is partially due to bad practice, i.e. "if you didn't do *this*, the question wouldn't have come up", even though the actual subject matter of the question is not really related to the bad practice. And while `using namespace std;` is not a particularly good idea, the real bad practice as in "why would you even do that?" is naming a function `cout`. But this is just a guess, I'm not a mind reader.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I know it's a bad practice and all. But I happen to notice it with `cout` and came here right away. Maybe I should put this up with another example without even any namespace?

Comment: @MichaelD.Blake No, your question is fine IMO. I was just trying to explain why you're getting downvotes. Sometimes you just have to live with it. Haters gonna hate.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I agree, but this is a community and if I don't make the majority feel happy, I won't be able to ask anything.

Comment: @MichaelD.Blake You're getting more upvotes than downvotes, so the majority is happy ;-)